# How to customize gnome theme?

Tags: gnome, icons

I'd like to replace icons, edit colors and maybe some more functionality. Is there a software for doing this? Or i should do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome itself uses GTK themes. [Here is a tutorial for use with Gnome 2.2+](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes) courtesy of live.gnome.org. This should cover the basics of editing themes, or creating your own.